# How to make a child div fill all remaining horizontal space of its parent div in HTML?

Tags: css, html

[test http://o7.no/U5w2EV](http://o7.no/U5w2EV)

The structure for this is:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='play'>▶</div>
    <div id='res'>RES</div>
    <div id='bar'>test</div>
    <div id='time'>0</div>
</div>
```

The styles are:

for #container

```
 #container
{backgroundColor:'#CCCCCC',
position:'absolute',
bottom:'-40px',
width:'100%',
height:'40px'}
```

for Buttons #res and #bar

```
#res , #bar
 {width:30px; 
 height:30px; 
 border:1px solid #DDDDDD; 
 margin:5px; 
 font-weight:bold; 
 cursor:pointer; 
 float:left}
```

for #time

```
#time
 {float:'left',fontSize:'16px',margin:'12px 5px'}
```

Note: the width of the container of the container (where it takes the 100%) changes dinamically.

How to set the CSS as to the #bar div fill all the space remaining from the other divs?

Comment: Depends on what spacial styles you've applied to the other elements so far.

Answer (score 1):

You've got incomplete code posted above. It's also formatted incorrectly (css).

But I "think" if you remove the css float on the inner `<div>`'s and instead make them `display: inline-block;` you should be able to declare CSS `width:` percentages on the inner `<div>`'s and have them fill your container.

Comment: It is because I copied from JavaScript objects representing CSS and made some changes without testing. Thanks, I'm reading about inline-block and testing your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `<div>` at the bottom after `<div id='time'>` and set the style `clear:both`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it with CSS in a satisfactory manner so I added a JavaScript listening to resize attempts which would keep it the right size mathematically.